# Confluent Schema Registry Kubernetess hangs

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to run Schema-registry server using helm charts from github hangs during startup when I deploy the kubernetess, kafka and zookeeper is up. I tried to Add DEBUG=true for more info but nothing prints. It was working great but i dont know what is happening. After the hang kubernetess just restarts the application and same situation happens. Kinly asking for help, how can I get more logs or information.

Also if i run this stack using docker-compose there is no issue. I guess it is about kubernetess configuration issue.

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                                              READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
vaultify-trade-dev-v1-s-kafka-0                                   1/1       Running            0          5m
vaultify-trade-dev-v1-s-kafka-1                                   1/1       Running            0          4m
vaultify-trade-dev-v1-s-schema-registry-6b4c57f998-kq5vv          0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   5          5m
internal-controller-54cb494qdxg   1/1       Running            0          5m
internal-controller   1/1       Running            0          5m
vaultify-trade-dev-v1-s-zookeeper-0                               1/1       Running            0          5m

$ kubectl get service
NAME                                                       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
kubernetes                                                 ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                      5d
vaultify-trade-dev-v1-s-kafka                              ClusterIP      10.109.226.220   <none>        9092/TCP                     8m
vaultify-trade-dev-v1-s-kafka-headless                     ClusterIP      None             <none>        9092/TCP                     8m
vaultify-trade-dev-v1-s-schema-registry                    ClusterIP      10.98.201.198    <none>        8081/TCP                     8m
internal-controller        LoadBalancer   10.100.119.227   localhost     80:31323/TCP,443:31073/TCP   8m
internal-backend   ClusterIP      10.100.74.127    <none>        80/TCP                       8m
vaultify-trade-dev-v1-s-zookeeper                          ClusterIP      10.109.184.236   <none>        2181/TCP                     8m
vaultify-trade-dev-v1-s-zookeeper-headless                 ClusterIP      None             <none>        2181/TCP,3888/TCP,2888/TCP   8m
```

https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/incubator/schema-registry

```
    ===> Launching ...
===> Launching schema-registry ...
[2019-02-27 09:59:25,341] INFO SchemaRegistryConfig values:
        resource.extension.class = []
        metric.reporters = []
        kafkastore.sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        response.mediatype.default = application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json
        resource.extension.classes = []
        kafkastore.ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        inter.instance.protocol = http
        authentication.realm =
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        kafkastore.topic = _schemas
        metrics.jmx.prefix = kafka.schema.registry
        kafkastore.ssl.enabled.protocols = TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
        kafkastore.topic.replication.factor = 3
        ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
        kafkastore.timeout.ms = 500
        host.name = 10.1.2.67
        kafkastore.bootstrap.servers = [PLAINTEXT://vaultify-trade-dev-v1-s-kafka-headless:9092]
        schema.registry.zk.namespace = schema_registry
        kafkastore.sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        kafkastore.sasl.kerberos.service.name =
        schema.registry.resource.extension.class = []
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm =
        compression.enable = true
        kafkastore.ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        avro.compatibility.level = backward
        kafkastore.ssl.protocol = TLS
        kafkastore.ssl.provider =
        kafkastore.ssl.truststore.location =
        response.mediatype.preferred = [application/vnd.schemaregistry.v1+json, application/vnd.schemaregistry+json, application/json]
        kafkastore.ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        authentication.skip.paths = []
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        websocket.servlet.initializor.classes = []
        kafkastore.ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
        access.control.allow.origin =
        ssl.truststore.location =
        ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
        port = 8081
        access.control.allow.headers =
        kafkastore.ssl.keystore.location =
        metrics.tag.map = {}
        master.eligibility = true
        ssl.client.auth = false
        kafkastore.ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
        rest.servlet.initializor.classes = []
        websocket.path.prefix = /ws
        kafkastore.security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm =
        authentication.method = NONE
        request.logger.name = io.confluent.rest-utils.requests
        ssl.key.password = [hidden]
        kafkastore.zk.session.timeout.ms = 30000
        kafkastore.sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        kafkastore.sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        kafkastore.ssl.key.password = [hidden]
        zookeeper.set.acl = false
        schema.registry.inter.instance.protocol =
        authentication.roles = [*]
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        schema.registry.group.id = schema-registry
        kafkastore.ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        kafkastore.connection.url =
        debug = false
        listeners = []
        kafkastore.group.id = vaultify-trade-dev-v1-s
        ssl.provider =
        ssl.enabled.protocols = []
        shutdown.graceful.ms = 1000
        ssl.keystore.location =
        ssl.cipher.suites = []
        kafkastore.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm =
        kafkastore.ssl.cipher.suites =
        access.control.allow.methods =
        kafkastore.sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm =
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        kafkastore.init.timeout.ms = 60000
 (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryConfig)
[2019-02-27 09:59:25,379] INFO Logging initialized @381ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog (org.eclipse.jetty.util.log)
[2019-02-27 09:59:25,614] WARN DEPRECATION warning: `listeners` configuration is not configured. Falling back to the deprecated `port` configuration. (io.confluent.rest.Application)
[2019-02-27 09:59:25,734] WARN DEPRECATION warning: `listeners` configuration is not configured. Falling back to the deprecated `port` configuration. (io.confluent.rest.Application)
[2019-02-27 09:59:25,734] INFO Initializing KafkaStore with broker endpoints: PLAINTEXT://vaultify-trade-dev-v1-s-kafka-headless:9092 (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore)
[2019-02-27 09:59:25,750] INFO AdminClientConfig values:
        bootstrap.servers = [PLAINTEXT://vaultify-trade-dev-v1-s-kafka-headless:9092]
        client.dns.lookup = default
        client.id =
        connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 120000
        retries = 5
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
 (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
[2019-02-27 09:59:25,813] WARN The configuration 'group.id' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClientConfig)
[2019-02-27 09:59:25,817] INFO Kafka version : 2.1.1-cp1 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2019-02-27 09:59:25,817] INFO Kafka commitId : 9aa84c2aaa91e392 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2019-02-27 09:59:25,973] INFO Validating schemas topic _schemas (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore)
[2019-02-27 09:59:25,981] WARN The replication factor of the schema topic _schemas is less than the desired one of 3. If this is a production environment, it's crucial to add more brokers and increase the replication factor of the topic. (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore)
[2019-02-27 09:59:26,010] INFO ProducerConfig values:
        acks = -1
        batch.size = 16384
        bootstrap.servers = [PLAINTEXT://vaultify-trade-dev-v1-s-kafka-headless:9092]
        buffer.memory = 33554432
        client.dns.lookup = default
        client.id =
        compression.type = none
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
        enable.idempotence = false
        interceptor.classes = []
        key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
        linger.ms = 0
        max.block.ms = 60000
        max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
        max.request.size = 1048576
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
        receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        retries = 0
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
        transactional.id = null
        value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
 (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig)
[2019-02-27 09:59:26,046] WARN The configuration 'group.id' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig)
[2019-02-27 09:59:26,046] INFO Kafka version : 2.1.1-cp1 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2019-02-27 09:59:26,046] INFO Kafka commitId : 9aa84c2aaa91e392 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2019-02-27 09:59:26,062] INFO Registered kafka:type=kafka.Log4jController MBean (kafka.utils.Log4jControllerRegistration$)
[2019-02-27 09:59:26,098] INFO Kafka store reader thread starting consumer (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStoreReaderThread)
[2019-02-27 09:59:26,107] INFO ConsumerConfig values:
        auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
        auto.offset.reset = earliest
        bootstrap.servers = [PLAINTEXT://vaultify-trade-dev-v1-s-kafka-headless:9092]
        check.crcs = true
        client.dns.lookup = default
        client.id = KafkaStore-reader-_schemas
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
        enable.auto.commit = false
        exclude.internal.topics = true
        fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
        fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
        fetch.min.bytes = 1
        group.id = vaultify-trade-dev-v1-s
        heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
        interceptor.classes = []
        internal.leave.group.on.close = true
        isolation.level = read_uncommitted
        key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
        max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
        max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
        max.poll.records = 500
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        session.timeout.ms = 10000
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig)
[2019-02-27 09:59:26,154] INFO Kafka version : 2.1.1-cp1 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2019-02-27 09:59:26,154] INFO Kafka commitId : 9aa84c2aaa91e392 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2019-02-27 09:59:26,164] INFO Cluster ID: yST0jB3rQhmxVsWCEKf7mg (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata)
[2019-02-27 09:59:26,168] INFO Initialized last consumed offset to -1 (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStoreReaderThread)
[2019-02-27 09:59:26,170] INFO [kafka-store-reader-thread-_schemas]: Starting (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStoreReaderThread)
[2019-02-27 09:59:26,200] INFO [Consumer clientId=KafkaStore-reader-_schemas, groupId=vaultify-trade-dev-v1-s] Resetting offset for partition _schemas-0 to offset 0. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher)
[2019-02-27 09:59:26,228] INFO Cluster ID: yST0jB3rQhmxVsWCEKf7mg (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata)
[2019-02-27 09:59:26,304] INFO Wait to catch up until the offset of the last message at 17 (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore)
[2019-02-27 09:59:26,359] INFO Joining schema registry with Kafka-based coordination (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry)
[2019-02-27 09:59:26,366] INFO Kafka version : 2.1.1-cp1 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2019-02-27 09:59:26,366] INFO Kafka commitId : 9aa84c2aaa91e392 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2019-02-27 09:59:26,377] INFO Cluster ID: yST0jB3rQhmxVsWCEKf7mg (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata)
```

This is my kubernetess deployment

---

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: vaultify-trade-dev-v1-s-schema-registry
  labels:
    app: schema-registry
    chart: schema-registry-1.1.2
    release: vaultify-trade-dev-v1-s
    heritage: Tiller
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: schema-registry
        release: vaultify-trade-dev-v1-s
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: schema-registry
          image: "confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.1.2"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8081
            - containerPort: 5555
              name: jmx
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 8081
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 5
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /
              port: 8081
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          env:
          - name: SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: status.podIP
          - name: SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS
            value: PLAINTEXT://vaultify-trade-dev-v1-s-kafka-headless:9092
          - name: SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_GROUP_ID
            value: vaultify-trade-dev-v1-s
          - name: SCHEMA_REGISTRY_MASTER_ELIGIBILITY
            value: "true"

          - name: JMX_PORT
            value: "5555"
          resources:
            {}

          volumeMounts:
      volumes:
```

More..

If I tell kubernetess to not restart I get this error

```
[2019-02-27 10:29:07,601] INFO Wait to catch up until the offset of the last message at 8 (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore)
[2019-02-27 10:29:07,675] INFO Joining schema registry with Kafka-based coordination (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry)
[2019-02-27 10:29:07,681] INFO Kafka version : 2.0.1-cp1 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2019-02-27 10:29:07,681] INFO Kafka commitId : 815feb8a888d39d9 (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser)
[2019-02-27 10:29:07,696] INFO Cluster ID: HoNdEGzXTCqHb_Ba6_toaA (org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata)

.
[2019-02-27 10:30:07,681] ERROR Error starting the schema registry (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication)
io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.SchemaRegistryInitializationException: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.SchemaRegistryTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for join group to complete
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.init(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:220)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.setupResources(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:63)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.setupResources(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:41)
        at io.confluent.rest.Application.createServer(Application.java:169)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain.main(SchemaRegistryMain.java:43)
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.exceptions.SchemaRegistryTimeoutException: Timed out waiting for join group to complete
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.masterelector.kafka.KafkaGroupMasterElector.init(KafkaGroupMasterElector.java:202)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.init(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:215)
        ... 4 more
[2019-02-27 10:30:07,682] INFO Shutting down schema registry (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry)
[2019-02-27 10:30:07,685] INFO [kafka-store-reader-thread-_schemas]: Shutting down (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStoreReaderThread)
[2019-02-27 10:30:07,687] INFO [kafka-store-reader-thread-_schemas]: Stopped (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStoreReaderThread)
[2019-02-27 10:30:07,688] INFO [kafka-store-reader-thread-_schemas]: Shutdown completed (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStoreReaderThread)
[2019-02-27 10:30:07,692] INFO KafkaStoreReaderThread shutdown complete. (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStoreReaderThread)
[2019-02-27 10:30:07,692] INFO [Producer clientId=producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer)
[2019-02-27 10:30:07,710] ERROR Unexpected exception in schema registry group processing thread (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.masterelector.kafka.KafkaGroupMasterElector)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.WakeupException
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.maybeTriggerWakeup(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:498)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:284)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:242)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:218)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:230)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.masterelector.kafka.SchemaRegistryCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(SchemaRegistryCoordinator.java:207)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.masterelector.kafka.SchemaRegistryCoordinator.poll(SchemaRegistryCoordinator.java:97)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.masterelector.kafka.KafkaGroupMasterElector$1.run(KafkaGroupMasterElector.java:192)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: For anyone looking for resolution, default replication factor for topics is 3 in kafka helm chart. In 1 node cluster schema-registry cannot initiate topic creation at kafka side error happens, just change default replication factor if this is the case

Comment: Feel free to put answer below, rather than as a comment

Answer (score 0):

As [tolga_kavukcu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1501845/tolga-kavukcu) mentioned in the comments:

> Default replication factor for topics is 3 in kafka helm chart.
>
> In 1 node cluster schema-registry cannot initiate topic creation at kafka side error happens.
>
> Just change default replication factor if this is the case